# How to make the border size same for all td sections of table in Bootstrap

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

*I was trying to set border for td. However, the border size looks disimilar. How to apply similar border size to all td sections?*

You can see the image reference here:
[image: Image of result(table)]

**Here is my Css part:**

```
  .table td{
             border: 1px solid #21ff11 !important;
                }
                
   .table{
           border-collapse:collapse !important;
                }
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of setting a manual border in CSS, try using the `.table-bordered` class from Bootstrap. You can also use `.border-success` for the green color.

[Tables · Bootstrap v5.0](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/content/tables/)

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-EVSTQN3/azprG1Anm3QDgpJLIm9Nao0Yz1ztcQTwFspd3yD65VohhpuuCOmLASjC" crossorigin="anonymous">

<table class="table table-bordered border-success">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th scope="col">#</th>
      <th scope="col">First</th>
      <th scope="col">Last</th>
      <th scope="col">Handle</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <th scope="row">1</th>
      <td>Mark</td>
      <td>Otto</td>
      <td>@mdo</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th scope="row">2</th>
      <td>Jacob</td>
      <td>Thornton</td>
      <td>@fat</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th scope="row">3</th>
      <td>Larry</td>
      <td>the Bird</td>
      <td>@twitter</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```